# How to add an item to an array by clicking a plus navigationBar button

Tags: xcode, ios4

I have an application with a view that have a tableView which is populated with strings from an array, and also have a navBar with a plusButton. What I want is that when I press the plusButton I want to be able to add items to that array.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add action method (`IBAction`) to that `UIButton` that is implemented in table view control class.
2. Implement in that method adding new object to your array
3. Reload table view (or call appropriate methods to add row one by one) after modifying array